# Suspending has started to require authentication

Tags: permissions, suspend, laptop, thinkpad, ubuntu-mate

My laptop has started to requiring authentication to suspend.
This means that it never suspends automatically when the lid is closed or power is low.
I am currently running 17.10. This was definitely not happening on 17.04
and I do not recall this happening when I first upgraded.
How do I revert to normal behaviour.

This is the dialog I see after closing and reopening the lid:

[image: Suspend Authetication Dialog]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit your `polkit` settings to allow anyone to suspend by

`sudo gedit /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy`

Locate the section that says `<action id="org.freedesktop.login1.suspend">`

Change the settings to:

```
<defaults>
    <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
    <allow_inactive>yes</allow_inactive>
    <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
</defaults>
```

Comment: Thanks! this seems to work. Any idea when & why this changed? I only started seeing the new behaviour recently.

Comment: I've been unable to get the "hibernate" equivalent of this to work.